# Display function not printing any results

Tags: c

I have written a `displayResults` function where I pass through all of my calculations into the arguments and print each line. 
The console application stays open each time it is asking for data, but as soon as it gets to the `displayResults` function the window closes.

I have already included the `system("Pause);` hoping it would keep the window open but it did not work.

The function I am referring to:

```
void displayResults(double force, double volume, char encodeTxt, double distance,
double tangent, double resist, double y)
{
    printf("The force = %lf\n", force);
    printf("The volume = %lf\n", volume);
    printf("The encoded character = %c", encodeTxt);
    printf("The distance = %lf", distance);
    printf("The tangent = %lf", tangent);
    printf("The resistance = %lf", resist);
    printf("The y value = %lf", y);

    system("Pause");
}
```

Here is more of my code:

```
double getForce(void)
{
    double force = 0, mass = 0, accel = 0;
    printf("Enter the mass:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &mass);
    printf("Enter the acceleration:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &accel);

    force = mass * accel;
    return force;
}

double getVolume(void)
{
    double volume = 0, radius = 0, height = 0;
    printf("Enter radius of cylinder:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &radius);
    printf("Enter height of cylinder:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &height);

    volume = PI * pow(radius, 2) * height;
    return volume;
}

char getEncode(void)
{
    char encodeTxt, plainTxt;
    int shift = 0;
    printf("Enter a character:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &plainTxt);
    printf("Enter an integer");
    scanf("%d", &shift);

    encodeTxt = (plainTxt - 'A') + 'a' - shift;
    return encodeTxt;
}

double getDistance(void)
{
    double distance = 0, x1 = 0, x2 = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0;
    printf("Enter first point:\n");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &x1, &y1);
    printf("Enter second point:\n");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &x2, &y2);

    distance = sqrt(pow(x1 - x2, 2) + pow(y1 - y2, 2));
    return distance;
}

double getTangent(void)
{
    double tangent = 0, theta = 0;
    printf("Enter the theta angle:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &theta);

    tangent = sin(theta) / cos(theta);
    return tangent;
}

double getResist(void)
{
    double resist = 0;
    int r1 = 0, r2 = 0, r3 = 0;
    printf("Enter three resistors:\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &r1, &r2, &r3);

    resist = 1 / (1 / r1 + 1 / r2 + 1 / r3);
    return resist;
}

double equation(void)
{
    double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    int a = 0;
    printf("Enter the a value:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter the x, y, z values:\n");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &x, &y, &z);

    y = ((double)2 / (double)3) - y + z * x / (a % 2) + PI;
    return y;
}
```

And lastly my main function:

```
int main(void)
{
    double force = 0, volume = 0, distance = 0, 
    tangent = 0, resist = 0, y = 0;
    char encodeTxt;

    force = getForce();
    volume = getVolume();
    encodeTxt = getEncode();
    distance = getDistance();
    tangent = getTangent();
    resist = getResist();
    y = equation();
    displayResults(force, volume, encodeTxt, distance, tangent, resist, y);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the console to display my results but after asking for the last x, y z values from my equation function, it ceases to work.

Comment: Try `char c;scanf(" %c",&c)` instead of `system("Pause");`

Comment: And add some newlines to your prints

Comment: @StephanLechner Neither is good. The real solution is to configure the IDE/debugger such that it keeps the output window open after the application terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
y = ((double)2 / (double)3) - y + z * x / (a % 2) + PI;
```

My first though is that a might be even, so that a%2 == 0, and you cannot divide by zero.
As soon as something/0 gets evaluated, the program stops.

You can try to print something before and after this calculation to see if I'm right.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I overlooked that. I subconsciously was picking even numbers for my a value the whole time. That lead to a 0 in the denominator. Thanks

Comment: "…the program stops" That is not guaranteed.

Comment: @PostyToasty, If you write `(2.0/3.0)` you don't need to `((double)2/(double)3)` making that way your code more readable.  The difference between floating point literals and integer is that they have a decimal dot somewhere in the number.

Answer (score 0):

This is a divide-by-zero issue introduced by the following function

```
double getResist(void)
{
    double resist = 0;
    int r1 = 0, r2 = 0, r3 = 0;
    printf("Enter three resistors:\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &r1, &r2, &r3);

    resist = 1 / (1 / r1 + 1 / r2 + 1 / r3);
    return resist;
}
```

I just debugged your program, you are inputing r1, r2 and r3 as integer. Thus,

```
1 / r1 + 1 / r2 + 1 / r3 = 0 !
```

There will be 'Floating point exception' here.

The solution is to declare r1, r2 and r3 as double.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My only problem is the question specifically asked me to declare the r1, r2, r3 variables as integers. However, I suppose I could just typecast them as doubles, as they would still be declared as integers.